# Guide To Setting Accessing PhpMyAdmin On NGINX, Ubuntu 11.04, EC2 Remote MySQL Instance

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, nginx

I have setup a domain name to run on amazon ec2 running ubuntu 11.04, nginx and php5-fpm.

The domain name works great, I have setup it's own sites-available configuration file and sym-linked it to sites-enabled.

I installed phpmyadmin via **sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin** and followed the instructions.

I then added this just above my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and restarted nginx.

```
server {
        listen    80;
        server_name     phpmyadmin.domain.com;

        location / {
                root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
                index index.php;
        }

        #make sure all php files are processed by fast_cgi
        location ~ \.php {
                # try_files $uri =404;

                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

}
```

I have also added the appropriate dns A records for phpmyadmin.domain.com

phpmyadmin.domain.com just shows a 404 error code. All other subdomains do not respond at all so at least something is working here.

FYI I have edited the /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file so that I can connect to a remote MySQL Database.

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the nginx `root` directive in .php `location` block

something like this:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root   /path/to/public_html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        include     fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All that was needed was a simply symlink between /usr/share/phpmyadmin and my default web folder.